# keep getting rate limited python api

Tags: python, twitter

ok so im really new to python and I am trying to create to assist me in marketing my music via social media. I am trying to code it so that when I compare a users followers with my followers if I am not following one of their followers, it automatically follows them. here is what I have

```
import twitter
import time
now = time.time
username = raw_input("whos followers")
api = twitter.Api(...)
friendslist = api.GetFollowersPaged(screen_name=username, count=1,)
myfollowers = api.GetFollowersPaged(user_id=821151801785405441, count=1)
for u in friendslist:
    if u not in myfollowers:
        api.CreateFriendship(u.friendslist)
    print 'you followed new people'
time.sleep(15)
```

I am using python 2.7 and the python-twitter api wrapper my error seems to start at the api.CreateFriendship line. also I set the count to 1 to try to avoid rate limiting but hae had them as high as 150, 200 being the max

Answer (score 0):

The Twitter API has fairly subjective controls in place for Write operations.  There are daily follow limits and they designed to limit exactly the sort of thing you are doing.

see https://support.twitter.com/articles/15364 and https://support.twitter.com/articles/15364

> If you do reach a limit, we'll let you know with an error message
>   telling you which limit you've hit. For limits that are time-based
>   (like the direct messages, Tweets, changes to account email, and API
>   request limits), you'll be able to try again after the time limit has
>   elapsed.

Comment: thank you. is there a way to list a users followers in tkinter with an option to follow them to assure I stay withing the follow limits?

Comment: Not as far as I know.  I would just prioritise who you follow if that is possible, and handle the error gracefully each day and wait until the reset time.